# Set new value with computed properties

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, computed-properties

i have a model object and i want to set new value to the object.

bellow i have mentioned the object variable and initialization

```
private var _data: NSMutableDictionary

// MARK:- Init
init(data: [String: AnyObject])
{
    _data = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: data)
}
```

How can i set a new value with setter. bellow i have mentioned the computed variable

```
var name: String? {

    get {
        if let nameObject = _data.objectForKey("network")?.objectForKey("name") {
            return (nameObject as! String)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    set {

    }
}
```

need to complete the setter

**Edit**

I could found the answer for this question.

I need to change the name of the _data object. So i have to update name without change other variables in side the _data. so i keep a mutable copy of the _data object and changed the new value there. then updated the _data object.

Comment: You told us what you want to achieve, but you didn't tell us what issues did you run into.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
set {
    _data.objectForKey("network")?.setObject(newValue, forKey: "name")
}
```

Comment: it gives the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd240dcf180"

Comment: So what exactly is in the dictionary? You need to call an appropriate setter function on that object.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var name: String? {

    get {
        return _data["network"]?["name"] as? String
    }

    set {
        if let network = _data["network"] as? Dictionary {
            network["name"] = newValue
        } else {
            let network: [String:AnyObject] = ["name": newValue]
            data["network"] = network
        }
    }
}
```

The setter also takes care of the situation the `network` key doesn't exist. If also `_data` can be `nil` then an extra `if-let` can be added to address this situation too.

BTW, I also added a shorter version of the getter.

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure what you are trying to do here but can't you just write this:

```
set {
    _data.objectForKey("network")?.objectForKey("name") = newValue
}
```

Edit: Wrong function, should have been:

```
set {
    _data.objectForKey("network")?.setObject(newValue, forKey: "name")
}
```

Comment: I have tried it before. it gives an error "Can not assign to value: function call returns immutable value"

Comment: Here i am creating a model object. so i want to write the set option. according to the theory seems your answer is correct. but i could not understand the error